# In php how would I generate a fixed number from a string within a certain value range

Tags: php, random

Let's say I have a database of 100,000 more or less random strings and I want to generate a number from each string between 1 and 500.

My method should always generate the same number (given the same string) and it should be an even distribution of numbers from 1 to 500.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for your own string encoding method? :o

Comment: Use a CRC (PHP's crc32() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php), then adjust the result to fit your range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need a hashing function. You can use [`crc32`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) and [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
echo abs(crc32("hello world")) % 500 + 1;
```

Comment: Please note that crc32() returns a signed integer and thus it can be -1234567. For use in my case adding abs() around the crc32() function did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like:

```
function string_to_decimal($hex_str)
{
    $arr = str_split($hex_str, 4);
    foreach ($arr as $grp) {
        $dec[] = str_pad(hexdec($grp), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return implode('', $dec);
}
```